# Abstract method vs static method in Program class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Say I've got a simple inheritance chain where `Employee` is the abstract base class and `Checkout` and `Manager` inherit from it in this purely illustrative console app.  Now I want to have a method that will take in an object of type `Manager` or `Checkout` and return an integer amount of a bonus depending on the position in the company of the employee.  I had some initial thoughts on doing this, and would like to know potential long-term deficits or gains from each approach if this console app were to one day grow up to be a data-driven web application.

1. Use an interface common to the inherited classes.
   My base class looks like

   ```
   abstract class Employee
       {
           public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
           public string FirstName { get; set; }
           public string LastName { get; set; }


       }
   ```

   and my derived classes implement an interface designed to print employee information to the console called `IPrintable` and only has one method to do so.  Although this interface has nothing to do with giving bonuses I mocked up the following in the class with my `Main` method lives and the program runs fine.

   ```
   static int GiveBonusesViaInterface(IPrintable i)
           {
               if (i is Checkout)
                   return 1000;
               else 
                   return 2000;


           }
   ```

   It seems to me that if I wanted to use an interface for this I should probably make another one specific to giving raises instead of riding the coattails on an already-implemented interface (but that's another question for another day).
2. Use a static method in the base class like

   ```
   public static int GiveBonus(Employee e)
           {
               if (e is Manager)
                   return 2000;
               else
                   return 1000;
           }
   ```
3. Make an abstract method in the abstract base class and nave derived classes implement as they see fit

   ```
   abstract class Employee
   //fields and constructors
   {
   public abstract int GiveBonusesViaAbstractMethod(Employee e); 
   }
   ```

This seems to be the worst idea to me because there will have to be a method in each derived class that takes in a parameter of `IPrintable` or `Employee` type and in the Manager class we'd have to test if the employee `is-a` Manager.

Are 1-2 equally as scalable and managable for a long-term web application?  Is option 3 really as bad as I made it out?

Comment: I think the exist approach (using interface) is better than other

Comment: Oh, no, this is getting worse.  Don't spread your logic out, and definitely don't put it in your static class with `Main`.  Writing a static method is fine, but put it in the abstract `Employee` class - if you must have a method at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you really have already answered your own question.

> my derived classes implement an interface designed to print employee information to the console called `IPrintable` and only has one method to do so. Although this interface has *nothing to do with giving bonuses*

[emphasis mine]

You already have an interface for this.  It's called `Employee`.  The idiomatic way to do to this is to implement a virtual method on your abstract class and override if necessary.  The more idiomatic C# approach is to write a property and override it.  Like so:

```
abstract class Employee {
  public virtual int GetBonus()
  {
    return this.Bonus;
  }

  public virtual int Bonus { get; set; }
}

class Manager : Employee {
  public override int Bonus 
  { 
    get { return 2000; }
  }
}

class Checkout : Employee {
  public override int Bonus
  {
    get { return 1000; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this a more OO approach than making a static method in the Employee base class?

Comment: I don't know that I would call it "more OO", necessarily.  A static method could just as easily be used. You would just have to pass an `Employee` parameter and use that instead of `this`.

Comment: My initial reasoning for making the method static was that I would only ever have to change the return values (say if the logic became more complex) in one spot.  Would that be a valid concern, or something silly to worry about?

Comment: Whether or not the method is static doesn't affect how many places you would have to edit to make changes.  You don't need to override the method at all.  Really, you don't need a method - unless you're doing something really complicated to calculate bonus amounts.  Better is to just have properties.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the traditional OO way of doing this:

```
abstract class Employee {
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public abstract int GetBonusAmount();
}

class Manager : Employee {
    public override int GetBonusAmount() { return 2000; } 
}

class Checkout : Employee {
    public override int GetBonusAmount() { return 1000; } 
}

Console.WriteLine(someEmployee.GetBonusAmount());
```

Comment: `public override int BonusAmount{get{return 1000;}}`

Comment: @SamIam Yep, an abstract property would work equally well here. It all depends on the implementation - if it's a dynamic or calculated value, I'd probably go with a method. Not that it matters since it's the same code anyway, just a style thing.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a GetBonus() method in both the subclasses. You should avoid doing "is instance of" checks altogether.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie you don't need to know.  Leverage the type system.  That's the whole point of inheritance and polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I think abstract works well :

```
abstract class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public abstract int GetVariableBonus();
}

class Manager {
    public int GetVariableBonus(){
         return 2000;
    }
}

class Employee{
    public int GetVariableBonus(){
         return 1000;
    }
}
```

Is that what you need ?

Comment: that's essentially the same, but I opted for making the abstract method static since I would only have to potentially change the return values in one class (the base class) vs all inherited ones.

Comment: @woots That violates the Open Closed principle. Classes should be open for extension, closed for modification.